# File is not replaced during deployment

Tags: wix

After successful upgrade of the product, one file were not replaced for unknown reason (MSI log is missing). This is not a DLL file where the problem would probably be version. It is some custom binary file that (important note) during lifetime of older version was manually overwritten with newer file. Is there way to force file replacement?

This is how file node looks like:

```
<Component Win64="yes" Id="cmpSOMEFILE" Guid="*">
<File Id="filSOMEFILE" KeyPath="yes" Source="SOMEFILE.dll.sig" /></Component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the file to always be replaced, then how about using a `<RemoveFile>` in the same component to cleanup the file first. 
The RemoveF0iles action should be scheduled before the InstallFiles and the file will be removed and replaced with the newer copy every time.

Refer this:
http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Using-wix-how-to-always-overwrite-a-file-td6904118.html